# Most optimal way to increment or initialize an Int in a Swift Dictionary

Tags: swift

Given a directory and a key, I want to increment the value of that key if it exist in the dictionary, or initialize it to 1.

The dictionary type is Dictionary, but by design the value type for this key will always be an Int since it would only be changed by this code.

The code I have so far is below, but would like to optimize it, in swift style.

```
let v = dict[key] as? Int
if v != nil {
    dict[key] = v! + 1
} else {
    dict[key] = 1
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Update**

Since Swift 4 you can use a default value in the subscript (assuming the dictionary has `Value == Int`):

```
dict[key, default: 0] += 1
```

You can read more about it in the Swift Evolution proposal [Dictionary & Set Enhancements](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0165-dict.md) under [Key-based subscript with default value](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0165-dict.md#2-key-based-subscript-with-default-value)

---

One way would be to use the nil coalescing operator:

```
dict[key] = ((dict[key] as? Int) ?? 0) + 1
```

If you know the type of the dictionary you can almost do the same but without casting:

```
dict[key] = (dict[key] ?? 0) + 1
```

**Explanation**:

This operator (`??`) takes an optional on the left side and a non optional on the right side and returns the value of the optional if it is not `nil`. Otherwise it returns the right value as default one.

Like this ternary operator expression:

```
dict[key] ?? 0
// is equivalent to
dict[key] != nil ? dict[key]! : 0
```

Comment: I think the right hand side of ?? may be an optional as well, so the result would be an optional, and if you have nil ?? nil then the result would be nil. Handy for things like (firstChoice ?? secondChoice ?? thirdChoice ?? defaultValue)

Comment: @gnasher729 You're right. Since the operator is overloaded with a version that takes an optional on the right side.

Answer (score 5):

you can try this:

```
dict[key, default:0] += 1
```

When `dict[key, default: 0] += 1` is executed with a value of key that isn’t already a key in key, the specified default value (0) is returned from the subscript, incremented, and then added to the dictionary under that key.

[see apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894528-subscript)

Answer (score 0):

The more readable swift style would be:

```
if let v = dict[key] as? Int {
    dict[key] = v + 1
} else {
    dict[key] = 0
}
```